# XPDL - error generating JAXB classes

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, bpmn, unmarshalling

In a project for my company, I am working to build a very simple Business Process Engine. To do that I have start from strudying of BPMN and now I am currently going in deep of XPDL.
I downloaded the XPDL xsd from http://www.xpdl.org/ and I tried to generate classes from this xsd, using xjc and its wrapping eclipse plugin.
It fails because conflicting error like the following

```
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] Property "TimeDate" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
  line 3558 of file:/home/alberto/Job/WSP/orch/orch.model/src/main/resources/bpmnxpdl_40a.xsd
```

Honestely I don-t know 
1) why an official and standard xsd like that has this kind of problem
2) how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

If you check out the `TriggerTime` element you will see there is an element and attribute called `TimeDate`.  This isn't a problem in XML, but by default the JAXB implementation will try to map both of these items to the same Java property which is causing the conflict.

```xml
<xsd:element name="TriggerTimer">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>BPMN: If the Trigger Type is Timer then this must be present</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element name="TimeDate" type="xpdl:ExpressionType"/>
                <xsd:element name="TimeCycle" type="xpdl:ExpressionType"/>
            </xsd:choice>
            <xsd:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="TimeDate" type="xsd:string" use="optional">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Deprecated</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>
        <xsd:attribute name="TimeCycle" type="xsd:string" use="optional">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Deprecated</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>
        <xsd:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

**The Solution (binding.xml)**

An external binding file can be used to customize how a JAXB implementation generates a Java modeld from an XML schema.  Below is an example that renames one of the generated properties:

```xml
<jxb:bindings
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="bpmnxpdl_40a.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='TriggerTimer']/xsd:complexType/xsd:attribute[@name='TimeDate']">
            <jxb:property name="timeDateAttr"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

**XJC Call**

The `-b` option is used to specify a binding file when using the XJC utility.

```
xjc -b binding.xml bpmnxpdl_40a.xsd
```